# Kendo Grid reading link tags in IE 11

Tags: kendo-grid, jaws-screen-reader, section508

I'm having an issue where if a cell contains a link to something, it reads the cell as "out of table" instead of saying that its a link and whatever text it is. Is there a workaround for this for IE11? It seems to work fine in Chrome. I'm using JAWS as well as the screen reader.

Comment: have you inspected the generated html code to make sure the link is contained in a <td>?  is there a `style` specified on the link or the <td>?  sometimes styles, especially the `display` property, can mess up the semantics for a screen reader.

Comment: yes its within the td and its styled on the link

Comment: can you post the generated html code that contains the <td> that's having the problem?  if a style is associated with the <td> or the <a>, post that too